# SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am running a node.js server running express.js on my local machine and need to decode a request made by the client, that contains a json string in it. I run the code below and get the following error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at C:\myLocation\source\repos\server\server\server.js:144:19
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\myLocation\source\repos\server\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\myLocation\source\repos\server\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
```

My request is

> http://localhost:1337/%7B%22Code%22:%22VNdVwY9iWhFZ114CjcDZbY%22,%22Chat%22:%22Test.txt%22%7D

The expected json is

> {"Code":"VNdVwY9iWhFZ114CjcDZbY","Chat":"Test.txt"}

I get the json, but it still gives me the same error.

My code:

```
app.use(function (req, res) {
    //console.log(req.url)
    var myStr = req.url.replace('/', '')

    if (myStr != false) {
        let decodeStr = decodeURIComponent(myStr)

        var test = JSON.parse(decodeStr)
        var json = JSON.stringify(test)

        if (json.includes(createkey)) {
            console.log("Create: " + json)
            createFile(req, res, test)
        } else if (json.includes(modKey)) {
            console.log("Modify: " + json)
            modifyFile(req, res, test)
        } else if (json.includes(readFileKey)) {
            console.log("Read: " + json)
            readFile(req, res, test)
        }
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(404)
        console.log("home")
    }
})
```

Why do I get the error?

**Edit 1**

I added `console.log(decodeStr)`but I still get the error. It returns `{"Code":"VNdVwY9iWhFZ114CjcDZbY","Chat":"Test.txt"}`

Comment: Please do a `console.log(decodeStr)` - that should tell us what's wrong with the string.

Comment: Why is there JSON in your URL path? That looks extremely messed up. Use POST to attach JSON.

Comment: {"Code":"'GAHGAaphgAP:gjpaGHAHAG{AaGRAP;GHPG;RA","Chat":"Test.txt"} is not a valid json

Answer (score 1):

{"Code":"'GAHGAaphgAP:gjpaGHAHAG{AaGRAP;GHPG;RA","Chat":"Test.txt"} is not a valid json, that's why you encounter that error,
The other way around, you could parse

```
JSON.parse('{"Code":"\'GAHGAaphgAP:gjpaGHAHAG{AaGRAP;GHPG;RA","Chat":"Test.txt"}')
```

Try

```
 var uri = "http://localhost:1337/%7B%22Code%22:%22%5C'GAHGAaphgAP:gjpaGHAHAG%7BAaGRAP;GHPG;RA%22,%22Chat%22:%22Test.txt%22%7D";
```

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: {"Code":"'GAHGAaphgAP:gjpaGHAHAG{AaGRAP;GHPG;RA","Chat":"Test.txt"} is not a valid JSON 
 var test = JSON.parse(decodeStr) will never work.

Comment: what makes you say that it is not valid json?

Comment: you need to escape the simple quote (')

Comment: I removed the single quote. i still get the error though

Comment: insteadof   var test = JSON.parse(decodeStr)
try JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(decodeStr));